# C# Reading database after SaveChangesAsync

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, asynchronous

If I do a write to a (ms)SQL database and saves the changes using SaveChangesAsync(), is there a possibility that a future read on the database could read unsaved changes?

Factors could include, whether a different DbContext, thread or process is used to access the database.

Comment: use `await` to wait for the async operation to complete before reading back the result.

Comment: use a Transaction for ensure ACID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer, NO (Tim P is mis-informed).

Calling `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync` will automagically create a `Transaction` for the duration of the saving.

This means that if any other thread tries to access the table, one of a number of things can occur.

Generally it means that the other Database call will block on the other thread, whilst the transaction is uncommited/not-rolledback.

Comment: So if only `SaveChanges` and `SaveChangesAsync` is used (i.e. not setting up custom `Transaction` or `IsolationLevel`), then no matter what kind of multi-thread/process you use, the EF calls are guaranteed to be safe? Would using `ExecuteSqlCommand` change things up a bit?

Comment: @Cardin I am not sure about using ExecuteSqlCommand. However, it is typical to loop on ExecuteSqlCommand, which would be an issue.

Comment: Another question, if table A has a FK constraint that makes it dependent on table B, would the `Transaction` be smart enough to know to block write access on table A, if table B is still being populated elsewhere?

Comment: Please read up on database transactions. It is unclear what you are asking, it sounds like a simple enough question, but until you develop the necessary jargon, I can't understand the question. By then you should have the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes.

It depends on several factors, such as how much you are saving to the database.  If you're saving 1,000 rows/objects, and it's a slow database server, it's possible that this time window is wide enough that another thread is reading while (for example) row #879 has yet to be saved.  And this has nothing to do with it being asynchronous. This is the normal concurrency problem in dealing with multi-user relational database systems.

Comment: I see.... I managed to avoid concurrency issue by putting a lock{} on methods that touch the same tables for synchronous code. I don't think I need to make my writes asynchronous yet (probably not the bottleneck) but was hypothesizing. Thanks!

Comment: @Cardin NOOOOOO you do NOT use `lock` on your DbContext. Databases have their own concurrency model which is far more effective than .net.

Comment: Last I checked `DbContext.SaveChanges` wraps the databases calls in a Transaction automagically. So that should be impossible.

Comment: Transactions will help if you block the calling thread with an "await".  However, if you kick off the process with Async (without an await) then you do run a risk of it not finishing the SaveChanges() before your next line of code executes.